# Mongoose error on using 'populate'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have schema for social network as following :

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name : {type : String},
    location : {type : String},
    picture :{type:String}
    social : {
        type : {
            followers : {
                type : [{user : {type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref : 'User'},date : {type :Date,default : new Date(Date.Now())} }],
                select : false
            },
            requests : {
                type : {
                    follow : {
                        type : [{user : {type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref : 'User'},date : {type :Date,default : new Date(Date.Now())}}]
                    },
                    select : false
                }
                select : false
            }
        },
        select : false
    }
});
```

There are other fileds as well for user schema but I am showing only required fields
I am trying to retrieve all the followers of a user, all the other users a user is following, follow request user has recevied and all the follow requets user has sent.
And all the users being retrieved must have only _id,name,location and picture.
This is what I have tried so far :

```
 exports.user_connections = function (req, res, next) {
    let userId = req.params.id;
    async.parallel({
        followers: function (callback) {
            User.findById(userId).select('social.followers').populate('name location picture')
                .exec(callback)
        },
        following: function (callback) {
            User.find({ 'social.followers.user': userId }).populate('name location picture')
                .exec(callback);
        },
        follow_requests: function (callback) {
            User.findById(userId).select('social.requests.follow').populate('name location picture')
                .exec(callback)
        },
        follow_requested: function (callback) {
            User.find({ 'social.requests.follow.user': userId }).populate('name location picture')
                .exec(callback)
        }
    }, function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        if (results.followers == null && results.following == null) {
            var err = new Error("No followers and following");
            err.status = 404;
            return next(err);
        }
        return res.send(results);
    });
}
```

But I am getting `CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value “{name : Username}” at path “_id”` error. Any suggestion what I am missing?

Comment: There seem to be a few problems here, but most centric are that you appear to be calling populate with the "fields to select" and not actually providing the **"path to populate"** which is what the main argument needs to be. i.e `User.findById(userId).populate({ path: 'social.followers.user', select: 'name location picture' }).exec()`. There also seems to be a lot of superfluous calls, but it should probably be a lot more obvious what you can strip out once you understand how [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate) actually works

Comment: @NeilLunn would not I need to first select the field `select('social.followers')` as it is hidden field and then `populate()`?

Comment: No you don't need to do that.

Comment: @NeilLunn if I don't select the field with `select('social.followers')`, it is showing `social` as `undefined` and it is working fine with `select('social.followers')`

Comment: Whichever then. I'd call that a bug since in reality, specifying a specific path in populate should override the inherited field selection. But in all honesty you have to admit that you are playing with features you clearly don't fully understand yet. So probably "less settings" would be a better option for you until you actually have a better understanding of the API. Just a thought, but it probably would make life easier for you right now if you took that advice.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for the suggestion.